# Should I use try catch or if else to check for foreign key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables, one for posts and the second for comments. The comments table contain the column `PostId` to link the table with the posts table. I write the following code to insert new comment :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult NewComment(int PostId,string Text)
{
     Comment comment = new Comments();
     comment.PostId = PostId;
     comment.Text = Text;
     comment.Date = DateTime.Now;
     using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
      return Json("Valid Comment");
}
```

The only error that can be occur is that the `PostId` value is not valid (There is no post in posts table that has a PostId the same provided by the client). My question is what is best to handle this error. Should I use try catch like this :

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    db.Comments.Add(comment);
    try
    {
       db.SaveChanges();
       return Json("Valid Comment");
    }
    catch
    {
       return Json("Invalid Comment");
    }
}
```

Or Should I check first if the PostId value is valid by doing this :

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var y = db.Posts.Where(x => x.PostId == PostId).SingleOrDefault();
    if (y != null)
    {
       db.Comments.Add(comment);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return Json("Valid Comment");
    }

    else
    {
       return Json("Invalid Comment");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based, but FWIW I'd go for the test. Your try...catch as it stands will catch any error and you'd only be assuming that it is because there is no ID in the DB

Comment: If, on the balance of things, the `PostId` is likely to be good, then I'd go against the previous comment, and just try and do the insert optimistically and act on errors if it goes wrong. If on the other hand, there is a high probability that the FK relationship will not be satisfied, then I'd specifically check before the insert.

Comment: What's certain is that you'll have to `catch` specific errors rather than assuming all errors mean the same thing.

Comment: Why is a user able to comment on a post that doesn't exist?

Comment: @test A user is able to post anything they like. Never assume that what they sent you is valid in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let it fail.  An exception should be thrown when a method cannot fulfill it's purpose.  If the purpose of a method is to insert a comment for a given post, it can not do that if the post doesn't exist.  Throw an exception.

Let the method that tells requests the creation of the comment decide how to handle the situation where your method is unable to do as requested.

You might want to control what excetion is thrown, but only if you feel that you can provide better/more information.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when saying: You might want to control what excetion is thrown, but only if you feel that you can provide better/more information.

Comment: @AhmedShamel: typically you let the excpetion pass up and it contains the details.  Sometimes you can identify the problem better than the method that throws.  In this case you'd have a sql exception, but you might be able to check and discover that it has been deleted or locked and so instead of letting your callers figure it out, you can help them by giving a more understandable reason than "foreign key vilation".

Comment: As I understand(and please say if I don't understand) you mean I can simply ignore the error at the server and let the ajax request at the client(for example) detect that the error has been occur.

Comment: @AhmedShamel: that is definitely one option.  It really depnds upon what you want the method to do.

Answer (score -1):

Neither - Have the DB Engine join the insert request to the foreign table; insert the resulting *relvar*; and return the number of inserted records. If the returned count is less than the transmitted count handle the error appropriately in code as a failure.

This mechanism will ensure that the foreign reference exists *precisely when the insert is attempted*, and not at some prior time when you happened to have checked its existence.

It also minimizes the number of hand-shakes between client and server, which will scale much more readily, and eliminates any temptation to hold a lock on the foreign table while waiting on the back-and-forth with the database.

Comment: I think this would be a significant diversion from the "Entity Framework Way™"

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by (Have the DB Engine join the insert request to the foreign table; insert the resulting relvar; and return the number of inserted records).